# how to create animated Rectangle on CanvasVirtualControl using win2d like in .gif?

Tags: uwp-xaml, win2d

how to draw an Animated rectangle in canvasVirtualControl like the below gif.I don't know to how to achieve this.can anyone suggest me?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Win2d, the recommended control for creating animation is `CanvasAnimatedControl` instead of `CanvasVirtualControl`. The former can be dynamically drawn at a rate of 60 frames per second.

If you want to use `CanvasAnimatedControl` to create a dynamically changing rectangle, you can write:

```xml
<canvas:CanvasAnimatedControl x:Name="canvas" Draw="canvas_DrawAnimated"
                              Width="400" Height="400"/>
```

```cs
Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 200);
private void canvas_DrawAnimated(ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
{
    var session = args.DrawingSession;
    session.DrawRectangle(rect, Colors.Green);
    if (rect.Width > 30 && rect.Height > 5)
    {
        // The rectangle change parameter here has no practical meaning 
        // and is only used for adjustment
        rect.Width -= 5;
        rect.Height -= 3;
        rect.X += 5;
        rect.Y += 3;
    }
}
```

You can dynamically adjust the initial size, reduced range and position of the rectangle according to your needs.

---

**Update**

If you need the animation effect of the ant line, here is an idea:

1. We can create a gradient (such as a black and white gradient) to simulate a dotted line
2. Draw a rectangle and use the gradient color as the border color
3. Constantly adjust the start and end points of the gradient color to form a flowing effect.

Here is an example:

```xml
<canvas:CanvasAnimatedControl   
       x:Name="CanvasAnimatedControl"                      
       CreateResources="CanvasAnimatedControl_CreateResources"
       Draw="CanvasAnimatedControl_Draw"
       Update="CanvasAnimatedControl_Update"
       />
```

```cs
CanvasLinearGradientBrush Brush;
private void CanvasAnimatedControl_CreateResources(CanvasAnimatedControl sender, CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args)
{
    CanvasGradientStop[] stops = new CanvasGradientStop[2]
    {
       new CanvasGradientStop { Color = Colors.White, Position = 0 },
       new CanvasGradientStop { Color = Colors.Black, Position = 1 }
    };
    //Create linear gradient
    this.Brush = new CanvasLinearGradientBrush(sender, stops, CanvasEdgeBehavior.Mirror, CanvasAlphaMode.Premultiplied)
    {
        StartPoint = new Vector2(0, 0),
        EndPoint = new Vector2(6, 6)
    };
}
private void CanvasAnimatedControl_Draw(ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
{
    CanvasCommandList CommandList = new CanvasCommandList(sender);
    using (var ds = CommandList.CreateDrawingSession())
    {
        ds.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, this.Brush);
    }
    args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(CommandList);
}
private void CanvasAnimatedControl_Update(ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, CanvasAnimatedUpdateEventArgs args)
{
    Vector2 space = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    this.Brush.StartPoint -= space;
    this.Brush.EndPoint -= space;
}
```

Comment: sorry,I'm not asking about this rectangle.i am asking about the big rectangle with stroke lines looks like dash(----) which are continuously moving or rotating.is there any way to draw that in canvasVirtualcontrol?

Comment: It seems that I am missing something, I have updated the answer, please check it